# How to push material to Mesh Renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> How can I push material at the end of meshRender Array?

**Here is my code**

```
[SerializeField] private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;


public void PushMaterial (Material newMaterial)
{
  if (!meshRenderer) return;
  meshRenderer.materials [meshRenderer.materials.Length - 1] = newMaterial;
}
```

[image: here is what I'm getting in inspector]

**NOTE!**

I'm sure the `newMaterial` reference is not null and also `meshRenderer.material = newMaterial` is working but I want to push it at the end of the Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Like this:**

[image: Solution]

Duplicate from [Unity Forms](https://answers.unity.com/questions/124794/how-to-replace-materials-in-the-materials-array.html)